# How to display data without redundancy

Tags: php

i want to display in my system just one record with the same id.
for example: 01,01,02,02,03,03.
I just want to display 01,02,03.

Comment: Where are you get this id list? From Database?

Comment: is this a string?

Comment: yes @DelwarSumon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array_unique() function removes duplicate values from an array. If two or more array values are the same, the first appearance will be kept and the other will be removed.

```
$number = "01,01,02,02,03,03";
$result = implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', $number )));
echo $result; // output 01,02,03
```

**Happy Programming**

Comment: thank you for your answer. i will try this code if it works in my system